# Why is the mean smaller than the minimum and why does this change with 64bit floats?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-accuracy, floating-point-conversion

I have an input array, which is a masked array.
When I check the mean, I get a nonsensical number: less than the reported minimum value!

So, raw array: `numpy.mean(A) < numpy.min(A)`. Note `A.dtype` returns `float32`.

FIX: `A3=A.astype(float)`. A3 is still a masked array, but now the mean lies between the minimum and the maximum, so I have some faith it's correct! Now for some reason `A3.dtype` is `float64`. Why?? Why did that change it, and why is it correct at 64 bit and wildly incorrect at 32 bit?

Can anyone shed any light on why I *needed* to recast the array to accurately calculate the mean? (with or without numpy, it turns out).

EDIT: I'm using a 64-bit system, so yes, that's why recasting changed it to 64bit. It turns out I didn't have this problem if I subsetted the data (extracting from netCDF input using `netCDF4 Dataset`), smaller arrays did not produce this problem - therefore it's caused by overflow, so switching to 64-bit prevented the problem.
So I'm still not clear on why it would have initially loaded as float32, but I guess it aims to conserve space even if it is a 64-bit system. The array itself is `1872x128x256`, with non-masked values around 300, which it turns out is enough to cause overflow :)

Comment: Please show an actual code example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `numpy` arrays are completely different from Python arrays, I assume you mean the former?

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit system, `A.astype(float)` will return a `np.float64` array.

Comment: I eventually figured it out, will edit post.
Didn't add code or array type because I wanted to keep it generic and not bring NetCDF into it :)

Comment: And @ebarr you're right, the fact that the system was 64-bit was the key, it forced it to go to the preferred precision, not the minimum required.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with large arrays, be aware of potential overflow problems!!
Changing from 32-bit to 64-bit floats in this instance avoids an (unflagged as far as I can tell) overflow that lead to the anomalous `mean` calculation.

Comment: It's rather loss of precision than overflow. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3236263/1639922